# How do I count multiple placeholders in a String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, counting

Given is a `string str` `'Hello <name1>, hello <name2> and hello <name3>'`

The `<nameX>`s are placeholders. How do I count the amount of different placeholders in this string?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)  if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Yes youre right, If I had an idea, I would've shared it. But as you can see I found a solution myself. Thank you for making stackoverflow a better place anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a more generic solution that handles placeholders starting from any number, with possible gaps inbetween, it's trivially easy with regex:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"<name\d+>").Count
```

That will return you the number of any placeholders. It's also easy to filter it by distinct placeholders:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"<name\d+>").Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().Count()
```

Comment: I tried it and yes, it works, except it counts the amount of placeholder but I need the amount of different placeholders. So using <name1> twice in this string should still return 1.

Comment: I added the distinct version as well!

Comment: Perfect, thank you!